Enum Array in Angular
How to display enum array in Angular?
I have an object with a enum array property and i want display in a html-component:
<ul  class="list-group list-group-flush">
         <li *ngFor="let prop of object.characteristics" class="list-group-item">
                     {{ prop }}
         </li>
</ul>

My characteristics value is = [Calm,Sozial,Fearful,Protective,Friendly]
I tried with object?.characteristics,
If I use {{object.characteristics}}, then it works: Calm,Sozial,Fearful,Protective,Friendly
In this case it works, I think it has something to do with route in app.module.ts:
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'object/:id', component: DetailComponent},
  {path: 'objects', component: ListComponent},
  ...
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'objects', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/objects', pathMatch: 'full' }  

Although the other properties are displayed, the object will not recognized:
<ul  class="list-group list-group-flush" *ngIf="object">
         <li *ngFor="let prop of tempObject.characteristics" class="list-group-item">
                     {{ prop }}
         </li>
</ul>

But I want to use a *ngFor Attribute

Could you show the values of object and puppy?

my bad, i prefer to use simple variable names. I corrected it

Could you share how you've defined your enum array for more clarity?
This seems to work for me :
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export enum Characteristic {
    Calm = 'Calm',
    Social = 'Social',
    Fearful = 'Fearful',
    Protective = 'Protective',
    Friendly = 'Friendly',
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-sample-component',
    template: `
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li *ngFor="let prop of object.characteristics" class="list-group-item">
                {{ prop }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    `,
})

export class SampleComponent {
    object = {
        characteristics: [
            Characteristic.Calm,
            Characteristic.Social,
            Characteristic.Fearful,
            Characteristic.Protective,
            Characteristic.Friendly,
        ],
    };
}


I have a list.component & detail.componet. every item will showed in detail.component.
list.component.ts:
objects: Object[]: new Object[];
list.component.html:


     <li *ngFor="let prop of tempObject.characteristics" class="list-group-item">
                 {{ prop }}
     </li>



In this case it works, I think it has something to do with route:
const routes: Routes = [
{path: 'object/:id', component: DetailComponent},
{path: 'objects', component: ListComponent},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'objects', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/objects', pathMatch: 'full' }
Although the other properties are displayed, the object will not recognized:


                     {{ prop }}
         

yup, it seems to be an issue with routes, do you mind sharing more details? i can't seem to understand where you're getting the id from in " {path: 'object/:id' "

you have right, I get the id in the detail.component.ts:
...
getObject(){
const theObjectId: number = +this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
this._objectService.getObject(theObjectId).subscribe(
data => {
this.object = data;
if (data.characteristic) {
this.object.characteristic = data.characteristic.map(
(char: string) => AnimalCharacter[char as keyof typeof AnimalCharacter]
);
}
}

Additionally, I created two buttons:

{{object.id}}


when I try to start it, I get the following error message:
X [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. [plugin angular-compiler]

Now I am sure, what the problem was, but I needed two steps:

The problem was in routes:


...    { path: '/puppy/{id'}, component: PuppyDetailsComponent },
...

I confused {id} parameter from SpringBoot with :id from Angular

a new file component.module.ts was created:


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DetailComponent } from './detail.component';
import { ListComponent } from '../list/list.component';
import { RouterModule, ActivatedRoute, Routes } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [DetailComponent],
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
    exports: [DetailComponent]
  })
export class ComponentModule { }


After that, everything worked out right
